# Pie3d flash charts

Tags: flash, charts

Is there a free flash library which I could use to generate pie3d charts inside my as3 project? Something like http://developer.yahoo.com/flash/astra-flash/charts/ only with pie3d.

Thanks,
Szymon

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [amCharts](http://www.amcharts.com) It has a 3D pie and it's free as long as you don't mind a small link back in the corner.